# XPath and SelectNodes Method

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

First I did see this but it did not seem to help
[XPath SelectNodes in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558870/xpath-selectnodes-in-net)

I am trying to read a SSRS report defination.

```
ReportingService report = new ReportingService();
report.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

string x = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetString( 
                           report.GetReportDefinition(ReportName));

//Remove a Character at the beginning of the document -- Char 65279
x = x.Replace(x.Substring(0, 1), "");
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
// This appears to be a reserved default?
//ns.AddNamespace("xmlns","http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition");
ns.AddNamespace("xmlns:rd","http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner");
xml.LoadXml(x);
```

Now I am looking for the Query node which should be under

```
Report
...
    DataSets 
        DataSet
            Query
```

Now if I look at some variables

```
  xml.Name = "#document"
  xml.DocumentElement.Name = "Report"
  xml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[12].Name = "DataSets"
  xml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[12].ChildNodes[0].Name = "DataSet"
  xml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[12].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[1].Name = "Query"
```

But the problem is trying a couple of things I can not get to this DataSets Node or any subnodes.   Example

```
 xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(".//DataSets",ns);
 xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("DataSets",ns);
 xml.SelectSingleNode("//Report/DataSets",ns);
 xml.SelectSingleNode("//Query",ns);
```

Both return null what am I doing wrong.

Edited using driis advice

Comment: Is the XML document using namespaces ? In that case, you need to include the namespace for your XPath, possibly using XmlNamespaceManager. http://www.google.dk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=XMlnamespacemanager

Comment: Yes two, xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"  I have to figure out how to incorporate that, thanks for the link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you guys for leading me down the right path, 
this also helped
[Using xpath and rdlc report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099723/using-xpath-and-rdlc-report)

So the answer is this, you can name your prefixes anything you want.
Uncommenting out the line

```
ns.AddNamespace("xmlns","http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition");
```

and changing it to

```
ns.AddNamespace("def","http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition");
```

Then the following works

```
 xml.SelectNodes("//def:DataSets",ns);
 xml.SelectSingleNode("//def:Report/def:DataSets", ns);
 xml.SelectSingleNode("//def:Query", ns);
```

Comment: Yes, you can name your prefixes anyway you want, **but never** like "`xmlns:rd`": `:` colons character is not valid part of a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

this shall return you all DataSets nodes in the `xml` XmlDocument:

```
xml.SelectNodes("//DataSets");
```

Note that this returns a `XmlNodeList` as a type on which you can iterate.

If you are sure the problem has to do with namespaces, have a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318545

Answer (score 0):

Then why don't you just do

```
XmlNodeList queries =  xml.SelectNodes("//Query");
//selects 'Query' node occuring anywhere

foreach(XmlNode query in queries){
  XmlNode dataSetForquery = query.GetParent();

  //do some other stuff with query here
}
```